# identify clicked button in Angular

Tags: angular

Using Angular 9, I am creating dynamically one button for each entry in a list along with some labels for each button.
Now trying to change the value on the label every time button has been clicked.

using

```js
onClick(event) {
    let button_id = event.toElement.offsetParent.id;
}
```

along with

```html
<button mat-button id="{{ product.id + '_more'}}" (click)="onClick($event)">
```

is not very reliable, it fails for Firefox for instance...
Wondering, isn't there a simple way to get the element id of the calling button?

Looking for something like

```html
<button mat-button id="{{ product.id + '_more'}}" (click)="onClick('{{ product.id + '_more'}}')">
```

but cannot get anything to work...ideas? thx

Comment: just pass the value to identify it. i.e. `<button mat-button id="{{ product.id + '_more'}}" (click)="onClick($event, product.id)"></button>`

Comment: that simple...it works! thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tommueller was right, it is that simple <button mat-button id="{{ product.id + '_more'}}" (click)="onClick($event, product.id)">